# How to SSH from one Raspberry PI to a Raspberry PI running inside VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I have a Raspberry PI running on 192.168.1.xx and I'm trying to SSH from this PI to a second PI running inside VirtualBoxVM.

On VM (using NAT) I have port forwarding enabled by:

Host Port -> 2222 Guest Port -> 22

However when I try to ssh from PI1 to PI2:

```
 ssh -p 2222 pi@localhost -vvvv
```

I get the following error:

```
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused
```

I can SSH into the PI2 from my MBP (so I know SSH is correctly set up), but cannot from PI1. I can't figure out why PI2 is only refusing connection from PI1?

Running `ifconfig` on PI2:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:41:cb:b4
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

Comment: You're running virtual box on the first Pi?? Is your VM using bridged networking? If so, it should have its own IP address that you should substitute for localhost in your ssh client command. Check the output of `ip addr` on the virtual pi.

Comment: No the first PI isn't running inside virtual box, it's an actual PI connected to my LAN via an ethernet cable. My VM is using NAT and I cannot give my virtual PI's static IP addresses, as they all must have an identical IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forwarding port 2222 from your host computer's network interfaces to your VM.

You are attempting to connect to port 2222 on `localhost` from your other computer.

You need to connect to port 2222 on the host machine, not your other computer.

```
ssh -p 2222 pi@ip_of_macbook_pro -vvvv
```

Comment: I can currently connect to VM from my host machine (MBP). I'm trying to connect to VM from my Raspberry PI - which is connected to my local network on 192.168.1.xx

Comment: I have two Raspberry PIs running, one is an actual PI board whilst the other PI is running inside VM.

Comment: @user10586757 — Yes, I said that and explained what you needed to change in this answer.

Comment: @user10586757 — A Raspberry Pi is a piece of hardware. You have one Raspberry Pi, one Macbook Pro, and one VM (which sounds like it is running Raspbian or another OS optimised for a Pi).

Comment: sorry I see what you mean!! Thank you for this, it worked!